# Anchor tag helpers rendering as plain text while loading from ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables, tag-helpers

Inside a Datatable trying to implement  server-side loading and from an AJAX call, a property is returning as text from backend api , The text values is HTML representation of anchor tag

```
OrderNo = $"<a asp-action=\"GetInfo\" asp-route-orderNo=\"{p.OrderNo}\" target=\"_blank\"> {p.OrderNo}</a>",
```

From console, i can see the text is coming as correctly from api  as below

```
"data":[{"orderNo":"<a asp-action=\"GetInfo\" asp-route-orderNo=\"AV22728Z\" target=\"_blank\"> AV22728Z</a>","location":"Has","agent":"......................................
```

This is rendering as plain text only at runtime in the  table column and not replacing as Anchor tag ie plain text  AV22728Z  is showing in column

The data table initialization is like

```
$('#shipments').DataTable({                
            // Ajax Filter
            ajax: {
                url: "URL_API",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: function (d) {                        
                    return JSON.stringify(d);
                }
            },
            // Columns Setups
            columns: [
                { data: "orderNo" },
                ......
            ]
        });
```

Comment: I am not able to recreate your issue. I get a working `<a>` link, as expected. Can you show us the end-result HTML you get? Is it simply `<td> AV22728Z</td>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link seems to be rendered as a valid html but the link doesn't work because it was not processed as an [anchor tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0). You need to generate url in controller by yourself

```
OrderNo = $"<a href=\"{Url.Action("GetInfo", new { orderNo = p.OrderNo})}\" target=\"_blank\"> {p.OrderNo}</a>"
```